# How to ignore or exclude a file when pull request in github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We have 4 branches, 1-dev, 2-qa, 3-staging, 4-master. We want to update and add some people in CODEOWNERS file in 1-dev, and 2-qa to 4-master's CODEOWNER's file will be retain. Since there are 4 reviewers for 1-dev and 2 reviewers for 2-qa to 4-master.

I tried adding .gitattributes file that contains:

```
 CODEOWNERS -diff
 CODEOWNERS linguist-generated=true
```

So  I tried to push this in all branches, and update the CODEOWNER file in 1-dev. But when merging from 1-dev to 2-qa, the CODEOWNERS file is still modified. How do I exclude or ignore this file when pull requesting? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is a way to avoid merging certain files, and GitHub doesn't support this because, in general, Git doesn't support this.  This question has been asked on the Git list, and the general answer is that while this is possible with a custom merge driver, it's not a good idea.

Since GitHub doesn't use custom merge drivers, you'd need to both create a custom merge driver and set it using the `merge` attribute in `.gitattributes` and then do all manual merges with a bot instead of letting GitHub do the merges.  That would allow you to do it if you really want to, but, as mentioned above, the Git developers don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it's not possible to use custom merge drivers when using GitHub Website?

Comment: Correct.  The program to run when using a custom merge driver exists in your configuration.  Git doesn't allow transferring configuration in the repository for security reasons, so GitHub doesn't even know what tool you're using for your custom merge driver.